# Jenkins installation fails on Ubuntu 20.04 with dpkg: error processing package jenkins (--configure)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jenkins, dpkg, jenkins-multibranch

I was trying to install `Jenkins` in my server `Ubuntu 20.04` with the following commands

```
wget -q -O - http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo deb http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian-stable binary/ > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list'
sudo apt update
sudo apt install jenkins
```

But installation fails with `dpkg: error processing package jenkins (--configure):`

```
Job for jenkins.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status jenkins.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript jenkins, action "start" failed.
● jenkins.service - LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/jenkins; generated)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2021-01-24 20:09:16 UTC; 13ms ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 1620107 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/jenkins start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 24 20:09:16 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time...
Jan 24 20:09:16 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 jenkins[1620107]: ERROR: No Java executable found in current PATH: /bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin
Jan 24 20:09:16 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 jenkins[1620107]: If you actually have java installed on the system make sure the executable is in the aforementioned path and that 'type -p java' returns the java executable path
Jan 24 20:09:16 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 24 20:09:16 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 24 20:09:16 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc3-01 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time.
dpkg: error processing package jenkins (--configure):
 installed jenkins package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 jenkins
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried [this, removing and again installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19457867/problems-installing-latest-version-of-jenkins), changing the content of `/etc/securetty` [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/341955/problem-in-jenkins-installation-on-ubuntu-12-04-3-lts) but none of them is working. I'm only facing this problem when I try to install `Jenkins` in server, while I tried to install my own laptop having `Ubuntu 20.04` it works fine.

Comment: Do you have java installed? What is the output of `which java`?

Comment: thanks java was not installed in server

Comment: was there any answer or resolution to this?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre
$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+7-post-Debian-2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.12+7-post-Debian-2, mixed mode, sharing)
$ sudo apt-get install jenkins
```

Oficial docs:
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/linux/#installation-of-java
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/linux/#debianubuntu

Answer (score 0):

## Using Java 8

`sudo apt remove jenkins`

`sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk`

`sudo apt install jenkins`

## Using Java 11

`sudo apt remove jenkins`

`sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk`

`sudo apt install jenkins`

Comment: This does not help for my situation. I could have other issues on my system.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).